# rails says asset isnt precompiled but they are! + S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2 app hosting assets with Amazon S3. I'm using capistrano to deploy it to Digital Ocean. Here is the assets part of the recipe:

```
task :precompile_assets, roles: :wrk do    
  run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
end

task :sync_assets, roles: :wrk do   
  run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sync:assets"
end
```

The sync task:

```
namespace :sync do
  desc "sync methods"

  task assets: :environment do  

    ################
    # sync with s3 #
    ################

    puts "Synchronizing public/assets/* with s3://#{AWS_CONFIG['bucket']}/assets/"
    system("s3cmd sync -P public/assets/* s3://#{AWS_CONFIG['bucket']}/assets/")

  end
end
```

And here is my production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{AWS_CONFIG['bucket']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Deploy works flawlessly, the assets are precompiled and sent to S3, I can see them inside my bucket and I can browse them in Chrome. But any page I access I get `ActionView::Template::Error (anyfile isn't precompiled)`.

This is happening with any file ... images, CSS, JS, etc.

### UPDATE

Just found out that Rails.configuration.assets.digests is returning nil in production. Maybe the problem is there, for some reason sprockets is not finding the manifest.yml.

I'm probably mistaken but seems like sprockets is not using the assets_host in config when looking for the manifest.yml.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L38

### UPDATE 2

I have copied only the manifest.yml from S3 and put it inside public/assets and the error is gone.

Comment: You could try to precompile them with the rake command `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: hi, im already doing this.

Comment: You might wish to consider the [`asset_sync` gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) to help with this